# Recommendation for handling multiple apps in google wallet

Tags: android-pay

I successfully integrated Google Wallet in one app, and now I want integrate it into another. However I can only sent one postback url. Anyone have any approaches to making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Wallet for digital*:

Since the postback url is set in your profile, if you *must* have unique urls, I don't think you can do so without new accounts.

Otherwise, if you can segment based on data (e.g. using the `sellerData` field), that might be an option...

Hth...